# React Native state management - useState not changing state on single action but on multiple actions

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-effect, use-state

I want to perform same functionality on hardware button press as on doneClick. My app has some tags. There are tags on the screen whose state is maintained in the backend. Upon clicking them, their state toggles. When I change the state of one tag, I can see that it's really changed. But when I don't change the state the below line makes the tags array to empty
When I use this

> const [allData, changeAllData] = useState([]);

My state is changed on single action. But when I don't select or unselect a tag and come back to previous screen, I see that no tags are selected and allData is just an empty array.

But when I use this

> const [allData, changeAllData] = useState(props?.selectedLifeStyle)

My state is not changed on single action. I have to either select two tags, or unselect two tags, select or unselect same or different tags, only then my state changes.

Here is full piece of code:

```js
const LifestyleScreen = (props) => {
  const [searchUniqueValue, setSearchUniqueValue] = useState("");
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [choice, changeChoice] = useState([]);
  // const [allData, changeAllData] = useState([]);
  const [allData, changeAllData] = useState(props?.selectedLifeStyle);
  const [limit, changeLimit] = useState(10000);
  const [offset, changeOffset] = useState(0);
  const [fetching, changeFetchingStatus] = useState(false);
  const [searchArr, newSearchArr] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.user !== null) {
      changeFetchingStatus(true);
      props.loginChange({ selectedLifeStyle: allData });
      debugger;
      changeAllData(props.selectedLifeStyle);

      let params = {
        limit,
        offset,
      };

      getData(
        getLifeStyleTags,
        params,
        (res) => {
          console.log(res, "res in lifestyle tag");
          changeFetchingStatus(false);
          changeChoice(res.lifestyle_tags);
          newSearchArr(res.lifestyle_tags);
        },
        (err) => {
          changeFetchingStatus(false);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        },
        props.user ? props.user.api_key : masterKey
      );
    }
  }, []);

  const doneClick = () => {
    if (allData.length === 0) {
      showMessage({
        message: "Select at least one lifestyle",
        type: "warning",
      });
    } else if (allData.length > 10) {
      showMessage({
        message: "Select at most ten lifestyles",
        type: "warning",
      });
    } else {
      props.navigation.goBack(null);
      props.loginChange({ selectedLifeStyle: allData });
    }
  };

  const saveLifestyles = (item) => {
    let counter = 0;
    let arr = allData;
    if (allData.length > 9) {
      for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
        if (allData[i].id === item.id) {
          arr.splice(i, 1);
          changeAllData([...arr]);
          counter = 1;
          break;
        }
        props.loginChange({ selectedLifeStyle: allData });
        if (allData.length == i + 1) {
          showMessage({
            message: "Only 10 lifestyle tags  can be added",
            type: "warning",
          });
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
        if (allData[i].id === item.id) {
          arr.splice(i, 1);
          changeAllData([...arr]);
          counter = 1;
          props.loginChange({ selectedLifeStyle: allData });
        }
      }
      props.loginChange({ selectedLifeStyle: allData });
      if (counter === 0) {
        arr.push(item);
        changeAllData([...arr]);
        props.loginChange({ selectedLifeStyle: allData });
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Maybe set up a snack, that would help in understanding the problem.

Comment: @SaachiTech let me know what's not clear?

Comment: @SaachiTech I just want either of 2 solution should work. In the above, I have discussed two cases of state and their result so that it would be easier for anyone to help me either ways

Comment: These 2 statements are confusing. `When I select or deselect a tag, I can see changes on previous` and `when I don't select or unselect a tag and come back to previous screen, I see that no tags are selected`

Comment: @SaachiTech let me clear this. It means there are tags on the screen whose state is maintained in the backend. Upon clicking them, their state toggles. When I change the state of one tag, I can see that it's really changed. But when I dont change the state const [allData, changeAllData] = useState([]); this makes the tags array to empty